# Large transaction on database A locks database B on the same server

Tags: sql-server, transactions, database-performance

I have multiple databases running on Sql Server 2012.

I have to run a large import script on this server. The import script is wrapped a transaction. It also calls out to a linked Sql Server 2008 server to pull in data.

When I run this import script, the other database timeout on all requests.

What is the best way to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traced the issue down to the server being really low on RAM. Added more RAM and the import completes fine and all other databases run with out being impacted.

Answer (score 1):

> other database timeout on all requests

SQL Server does not time out requests. Is your client that aborts, usually because the [`SqlCommand.CommandTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx) default 30 seconds. That being said, you still have a performance problem, so investigate it as a performance problems. Read [Waits and Queues](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx) to learn about how to identify bottlenecks in SQL Server. Read [The Data Loading PErformance Guid](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) to learn how to import properly (hint: it won't be 'large import in a transaction').

This has nothing to do with 'lock'.